# Powering 24 volt solenoid valve with Arduino uno

Tags: arduino-uno

Today I received normally closed solenoid valve which I am going to use in automated pot watering system , 
I realised the valve takes 24 dc volt as input and Arduino has maximum of 5volt , using some power booster I can convert it to some extent but I think 24 volt is too much .

So how should power 24volt solenoid valve from Arduino uno?[image]

Comment: Howmany power does the solenoid use? Get a 24V power supply, or your 19V laptop power supply may actually do the trick just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]Since the solenoid requires higher current than the arduino can provide you can use an alternative power source for the solenoid (maybe a couple of batteries) and switch it with a TIP120 transistor.

Comment: Got it here : http://www.instructables.com/id/Use-Arduino-with-TIP120-transistor-to-control-moto/

Comment: Yes that was my source when i first implemented it.

Comment: Actually I have plan to power over Ethernet if Arduino can handle 24 volt dc I can break part of voltage from same dc input to solenoid valve

Comment: Arduino Uno Input Voltage Limit

Comment: Input Voltage (limit)  6-20V

Comment: Well that's a problem than I would have to invest a little bit more, thanks

Comment: You can get a DC-DC (buck) converter, to step down the 24V to 5V.

Comment: Doesnt the transistor need a heatsink?

Comment: Using XL6009 I can convert 9 volts to 24 volts

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices:

1 - Preferably, use a N-channel MOSFET. Best for usage of voltage between 9 and 60, these are great little modules that can control voltage flow.

2 - Use a relay. A little more expensive, but can handle main's voltage.

Comment: Why PNP instead of NPN? How do you turn off a PNP with only 5V?

Comment: @Gerben, my bad...

Comment: An “NPN MOSFET”? You mean an N-channel MOSFET, or an NPN BJT.

Comment: @EdgarBonet An N-channel MOSFET. Could an NPN MOSFET also mean NPN BJT? Because I think I was clear enough by putting MOSFET in capitals.

Comment: A BJT can be either NPN or PNP. A MOSFET can be either N-channel or P-channel. There is no such thing as an NPN MOSFET.

Answer (score -1):

24V AC or DC?  Relay would be good for either.

Low Rds N-channel logic level MOSFET (IRFL540) would be good for sinking DC current.

Comment: The OP said "the valve takes 24 dc volt as input" in his question. I think that means 24VDC. Dat Ha recommended using a N-channel MOSFET back on Nov 15, 2016. Do you think your answer adds any new information that may help the OP or any future visitors to this question?

Comment: Dang, I need to remember to look at the dates of the original question! That's the 2rd or 3rd time I've been caught up like that.

Comment: Do you think your answer adds any new information that may help the OP or any future visitors to this question?

Comment: No, feel free to remove the whole thing.